# Republish app in app store and play store

Tags: app-store, google-play

My app is already in app-store and google-play-store. How to republish my app because I made changes. Please tell me the procedure. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention too much information, but I guess you want to release updates to the apps. It can be done by raising the app versions which is similar for both stores and resubmit for iOS and upload new apk for android.

Just bump up the version number

Comment: I have to publish the updated version, should I add as new version in iTunes Connect or should I make changes at the current version from manage apps in iTunes connect. Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot edit the app in itunes connect, have to make a new version, when once approved becomes available as an update in the appstore.

Also similar story for android unless you dont have a different method to update your app via APIs previously setup.

Answer (score 1):

New user interface is tricky if you are visiting after so many days:

1. Login to google android console at developer.android.com
2. Select your app.
3. Find **pricing and distribution** in **store presence**
4. Click **Publish** in **App Availability**